# scrollbar reaction to the parent div event

Tags: html, css

Need to change scrollbar iechange a background color when a cursor is over the scrolled area. Is it possible?

My failure attempt:

```
.scrolled:hover ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle of your problem and I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found by myself. a space is the cause 
not:

```
.scrolled:hover ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
```

but

```
.scrolled:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
```